# Apache Redirect Rule Needed.Thanks!

Tags: apache, redirect

everyone
I have one problem here.
My site is powered by Mediawiki,
which means, the visitors are supposed to visit links like this:

```
hxxp://www.example.com/wiki/SOMETHING
```

I want to redirect the user to the Main Page if he is trying to access something else:

```
hxxp://www.example.com/NOTwiki/SOMETHING -> hxxp://www.example.com/wiki/Main_Page
```

and

```
hxxp://www.example.com/NOTwiki -> hxxp://www.example.com/wiki/Main_Page
```

And "/wiki" is case sensitive,
which means:

```
hxxp://www.example.com/WiKi/SOMETHING    -> hxxp://www.example.com/wiki/Main_Page
```

I am using a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/example/public_html/mediawiki/
ErrorLog logs/AP/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

I am new on Apache and still learning.
Be specific,Please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question belongs on Serverfault. It should be moved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This config should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php
   RewriteRule .* - [L]

   RewriteRule !^wiki(/.*)?$ wiki/Main_Page [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

The RewriteCond/RewriteRule says "If the start of the path is not /wiki, rewrite all URLS to /wiki/Main_Page using a 301 redirect (R=301), and do not process any more rules (L)"

Comment: Thanks a lot mootinator!U r awesome!

Comment: I believe it can go inside the <VirtualHost> config block.  Alternately, you can put it inside a .htaccess file in the root of the web server.

Comment: Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.I use the following in my <Virtualhost> Alias /wiki /srv/www/docwiki/public_html/mediawiki/index.php

Comment: Right, because you've told it anything which does not start with /wiki gets redirected to /wiki/Main_Page and anything which does start with wiki gets redirected to index.php (which does not start with /wiki)  See my updated answer for a suggestion shortly.